# encoding increase the size string, but decode don't reduce it

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, smarty, decoding

I'm sending an string via an url.

The string I wrote is :

```
"tasse(s)", size : 8
```

When i transmit it from the url, it encodes the string, so it's like that :

```
 string(16) "tasse(s)"
```

and If I get more info, its :

```
string(16) "tasse&#40;s&#41;"
```

So, after receiving my parameter via url, it's possible to get back :

```
"tasse(s)", size : 8
```

Because "tasse(s)", size : 8 exist in my Mysql BDD, but when I compare it with "tasse(s)", size : 16, it consider they are not the same ..

Someone have an solution for that ?

Code :

```
{assign var="myUri" value=site_url("admin/deleteRowInRecipe/"|cat:$recette[$i]->id|cat:"/"|cat:$ingredient|cat:"/"|cat:$quantite|cat:"/"|cat:$unite)}   

<a href="{$myUri}"><input type="button" value="Supprimer"></a>
```

In my console firefox/chrome :

```
<a href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter_RECETTE-copie/admin/deleteRowInRecipe/52/curcuma/1/3/tasse(s)">
<input type="button" value="Supprimer"></a>
                        <br/>
```

Comment: Can you show some code? The kind of encoding you show shouldn't happen automatically.

Comment: I'm not encoding it. It seems it encode itself ...
In my console, I can see clearly "<a href="something/function/tasse(s)" ..

Comment: Where does the string come from?

Comment: I added the code. So like you can see, the href is good ..

Comment: Can you look in the actual source code instead of the DOM view? This kind of encoding is not something that the browser will add.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want `<pre>array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "52"
  [1]=>
  int(2343)
  [2]=>
  string(16) "tasse&#40;s&#41;"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
</pre>` , it's the [2] with size 16

Comment: Look in the real source code (through view -> source code), not the console

Comment: Yeah what I added is the source code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44124/discussion-between-choubidou-and-pekka-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are htmlentities, Code Igniter is somewhere escaping the parameter (or you're doing it inadvertently). To get the correct value you can use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(html_entity_decode("tasse&#40;s&#41;"));'
string(8) "tasse(s)"
```

Comment: I said I can get the correct value, it's not the problem, the problem is the size 16 and size 8, so when I try to do a comparaison in BDD, it doesn't works ..

Comment: If you convert the string into ascii it will return a string of 8 characters. Try it :)

Comment: This is likely correct, but it's arguably better to try and fix the root cause if at all possible.

Comment: I tried it with this function `public function string_to_ascii($string)
 {
     $ascii = NULL;
  
     for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
     { 
      $ascii += ord($string[$i]); 
     }
  
     return($ascii);
 }` 
The same thing ..

Comment: @Choubidou that is not the same thing, try `html_entity_decode($string)`.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree, but without code there's not much else we can do at this point.

Comment: Already tested  html_entity_decode($igd,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8") and   $igd = html_entity_decode($igd);


I think i'm gonna to die !

Comment: $ php -r 'var_dump(html_entity_decode("tasse&#40;s&#41;"));'
string(8) "tasse(s)"

Comment: Yeah it was this .. I was doing the test in a different variable .. I'm sorry and thanks you so much Marin and Pekka